# Ignore or resolve dependency conflicts in melos

Tags: build-runner, melos

I am getting started with melon. The `flutter pub get` and debugging/running app works fine. While doing `melos bootstrap` I am getting below errors:

```
Building package executable... (1.6s)
Built melos:melos.
melos.yaml: Multiple packages with the name `a` found in the workspace, which is unsupported.
To fix this problem, consider renaming your packages to have a unique name.

The packages that caused the problem are:
- a at ../../../repo/ci/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner_core-4.5.3/test/fixtures/with_dev_deps/pkg/a
- a at ../../../repo/ci/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_modules-2.9.0/test/fixtures/a
```

Sometimes the error dynamically changes to following (but same):

```
Built melos:melos.
melos.yaml: Multiple packages with the name `b` found in the workspace, which is unsupported.
To fix this problem, consider renaming your packages to have a unique name.

The packages that caused the problem are:
- b at ../../../repo/ci/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_runner_core-4.5.3/test/fixtures/with_dev_deps/pkg/b
- b at ../../../repo/ci/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/build_modules-2.9.0/test/fixtures/b
```

I have `build_runner: 2.4.6` in dependency of app `pubspec.yaml`.

I am not able to `ignore` the [package](https://melos.invertase.dev/configuration/overview#ignore) as it isn't in current directory. How to resolve this issue?